# How to unregister Automatic execution

Tags: raspbian

I made python code in Raspbian.
This code has while loop.
For my mistake, I register automatically execute this program whenever raspberry pi is turned on.
How can I get out of (escape) from this code?
I typed ctrl+c, d, etc.

Do I have to reinstall raspbian? TT...

Comment: You need to explain **how** you *"register automatically execute this program whenever raspberry pi is turned on"*, otherwise there's no way to tell you how to undo it.

Comment: How did you "register [this program to] automatically execute whenever raspberry pi is turned on"? If you show us how you did this, then we can help undoing this setup.

Comment: @goldilocks jinx!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you made it automatically run on boot you can fix it if you have a Linux PC or a Windows computer with software that can read ***and write*** to ext partitions (for example [Paragon](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/)). Many auto start scripts I have seen have lines in `/etc/rc.local`. Just comment out the line you added and plug the sd card back in your Pi and reboot.

Or sometimes going to `cmdline.txt` (no software needed) on any pc and adding `init=/bin/sh` will bring up a terminal in which you can disable the auto script from within your pi (in my experience this does not work if your auto started program halts the system).

Comment: I guess you mean `init=/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Yup, my bad, I fixed it!